# how to select sql by use where condition And , OR in one Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want query sql where Condition And and Or in one Query in Linq. I try to coding in this below but not work. I want to query where id in CEvaUserEva or EEvaUserEva  or OEvaUserEva but status must be 'success'
Plese help me.

```cs
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
    try
    {

        var result = (
            from pre in context.PreChanges
            join cus in context.PreEvaCustomers on pre.DocNumber equals cus.CDocNumber
            join env in context.PreEvaEnvis on pre.DocNumber equals env.EDocNumber
            join oth in context.PreEvaOthers on pre.DocNumber equals oth.ODocNumber

            join sta in context.StatusDocs on pre.DocNumber equals sta.SDocNumber
            select new GetAll
            {
                
                DocNumber = pre.DocNumber,
                Users = pre.Users,
                UserId = pre.UserId,
                CDocNumber = cus.CDocNumber,
                CEvaUserEva = cus.CEvaUserEva,
                EDocNumber = env.EDocNumber,
                EEvaUserEva = env.EEvaUserEva,
                ODocNumber = cus.CDocNumber,
                OEvaUserEva = oth.OEvaUserEva,
                SDocNumber = sta.SDocNumber,
                StatusDoc =sta.StatusDoc

            })
            .Where((g => g.CEvaUserEva == id || g.EEvaUserEva == id ||
                g.OEvaUserEva == id  && (g => g.StatusDoc== "Success"));


        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message + "GetC 47");
    }
}
```

Comment: How this pat `(g => g.StatusDoc== "Success")` even compile?

Comment: You typically need to group OR conditions in parentheses since AND has a higher precedence, so it essentially becomes `A or B or (C AND D)` instead of `(A OR B OR C) AND D`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it can not complie but I don't have idear how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parenthesis around the or block

```
.Where(g => (g.CEvaUserEva == id || g.EEvaUserEva == id ||
            g.OEvaUserEva == id) && g.StatusDoc == "Success");
```